# How to change RefreshControl swiping down height in ScrollView in React-native

Tags: react-native, pull-to-refresh

**Description:**

I want to change the `swipe down` length for RefreshControl in ScrollView, but there is no option to change `swipe down` length.

[image: rsz_screenshot_2020-02-19_at_70538_pm]

Currently I have to Swipe down too much.

**React Native version:**

```
System:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 22.70 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.17.0 - /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4697961
    Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native-log-ios: 1.0.1
```

**Expected Results:**

minimum swipe down for RefreshControl.

**Code:**

```
<ScrollView style={{scrollY: 0}}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} 
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} 
            refreshControl={
                            <RefreshControl title={'refreshing'} 
                                            tintColor={'red'} 
                                            onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)} 
                                            refreshing={this.state.refreshing} />
            }>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: no solution `react-native` at leat for now. If you wanna give a try you can to this external package [syrusakbary/react-native-refresher](https://github.com/syrusakbary/react-native-refresher#props)

Comment: you can use panresponder to get solution